# NRO account Tax related

Tags: income-tax, india, mutual-funds

I have NRI/NRO account in India from this NRO account I pay to some SIP funds every month.

So for this SIP fund's interest how income tax will be calculated I have confusion so pl. help by giving answer.

Answer (score 1):

> SIP fund's interest

Not sure what you mean. The gains are taxable as per regular tax rates. For example if you have invested 100 and sold the fund at 110, 10 is your profit and you would have to pay tax on this amount as per the tax brackets.